# Java "contains" not working properly

Tags: java, android, gson, overriding, contains

My class:

```
public class UserProgressModel {

    private String email;

    public UserProgressModel(String pEmail) {
        super();

        this.email = pEmail;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x) {

        if (x != null && x instanceof UserProgressModel
                && ((UserProgressModel) x).email.equals(this.email) == true) {

            return true;
        }

        if (x != null && x instanceof String
                && x.equals(this.email) == true) {

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 17 * hash + (this.email != null ? this.email.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

And after putting some objects via gson:

```
UserProgressModel[] userProgressArray;
List<UserProgressModel> retUserProgress = new ArrayList<>();

userProgressArray = gs.fromJson(fileContents,
                        new TypeToken<UserProgressModel[]>() {
                        }.getType());

for (UserProgressModel ele : userProgressArray) {

    if (ele != null) {
        retUserProgress.add(ele);
    }
}
```

I am unable to get true for the following code:

```
retUserProgress.contains("test@test.com");
```

I looped thru the array to verify that one object has the email.

Am I doing right? I think I have overridden the equals & hashcode.

Comment: Having your `UserProgressModel.equals(...)` tell you that the object is equal to a `String` is not in keeping with the general contract of the `equals` method. A `UserProgressModel` is not really "equal to" a string. Moreover, `myString.equals(myUserProgressModel)` will always return false, so you are creating an asymmetrical equality. Also, your string and your model instance will have different hash codes so they should not be pretending to be equal.

Comment: retUserProgress is a List... Not directly UserProgressModel , so maybe that is problem.

Answer (score 5):

Your equals implementation is incorrect. If you look at the contract for equals the implementation must be symmetric:

```
... for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
```

In your case you have a list of UserProgressModel objects, but you are trying to compare against a String. While you've implemented UserProgressModel.equals(String) you would still need to have String.equals(UserProgressModel) return the correct result. Since you cannot do that this implementation will never work in all cases. What you should do is two things:

Remove the check in equals for String because it will never work.

Use a mock object to check in the collection:

```
retUserProgress.contains(new UserProgressModel("test@test.com"));
```

As long as your equals method is correct within your own type (UserProgressModel.equals(UserProgressModel)) this should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check if the retUserProgress contains e-mails because it does not. The ArrayList contains objects of Class: UserProgressModel, thus you can check if the ArrayList contains a 'UserProgressModel'.

What you would like to do is the following

```
private boolean containsEmail(List<UserProgressModel> retUserProgress, String email) {
    boolean result = false;

    for (UserProgressModel object : retUserProgress) {
        if (object.equals(email))
            result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And the call the method like so:

```
containsEmail(retUserProgress, "test@test.com"); //This will return a true or false, depending if the ArrayList retUserProgress contains the email
```

Answer (score -2):

i have tested your code in ideone

and it's working

[true](https://ideone.com/Si0xzs)

```
UserProgressModel model=new UserProgressModel("test@test.com");
System.out.print(model.equals("test@test.com"));
```

[false](https://ideone.com/2HQ9dP)

```
UserProgressModel model=new UserProgressModel("test@test.com");
System.out.print(model.equals("test@test.co"));
```

try to compare with new object

```
retUserProgress.contains(new UserProgressModel("test@test.com"))
```

[result](https://ideone.com/ji2xO1)

if you don't wanna compare with a new UserProgressModel you need to create your own list type that when it compare two object (UserProgressModel,string) it creates a new UserProgressModel and pass that email for it